# Capacitor use in H-Bridge circuit

Tags: capacitor, h-bridge, sparkfun

I am trying to understand how an H-Bridge circuit works.  The following is the diagram, from SparkFun's [TB6612FNG](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14451) product:

[image]

Specifically, what purpose do the C1, C2 and C3 capacitors serve? *If they were not present in the circuit, what would happen?*

(Disclaimer: Software engineer, lacking the deep fundamentals of electronics.)

**EDIT**:

Comments and one answer (so far) mention that capacitors need to be close to the IC.  Following is the image of the board; to my untrained eye, the capacitors seem to be located close to the IC.

[image]

However, the answer offered and comments seem to disagree.  One school of thought (by Maxim Ivanov) is that the capacitors provide protection against sagging voltage, while comments say they are for noise suppression.  Not sure how to proceed here.

Comment: electrical noise suppression - circuit would work without them **but** be prone to spurious operation.

Comment: VM is the motor supply voltage and Vcc is the supply voltage to the logic circuits. Without these caps the circuit probably still works but would generate much more noise [datasheet here](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/TB6612FNG.pdf)

Comment: They are called bypass or decoupling capacitors. They provide charge to the IC when it is switching and requires a sudden increase in current. This reduces noise on the power supply lines as well. The power supply cannot provide the sudden change in current because of inductance in power distribution system.

Comment: They are decoupling capacitors. The polarized (electrolytic) one, C3, suppresses low-freq noise (e.g. ripples coming from power supply) and the non-polarized one (probably ceramic), C1, suppresses high-freq noise (e.g. parasitics, low-level spikes). C2 acts as C1. Note that C2 should be placed as close to the VCC pin as possible.

Comment: about your edits: "sagging voltage", "noise" are similar-enough in this context. Hopefully, this board will be fairly  close to the load (motors?). These capacitors smooth supply voltage over a very short-time-frame: especially those moments when the H-bridge switches...which is quite often (likely thousands of switches-per-second). I see everyone here agreeing with different wording.

Comment: @glen_geek Thank you, I have accepted the answer that mentioned voltage sagging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Digital ICs often consume current in short but relatively strong pulses as they switch. These capacitors act as local power sources that can supply these pulses. Without them, power supply voltage would sag momentarily, which may upset the operation of the IC or its neighbours.

Comment: **local** supply means that these capacitors should be placed very close to the chip (VM1,VM2,VM3,GND)

Answer (score 1):

What a decoupling capacitor does is suppress high-frequency noise in power supply rails. They might take small voltage ripples, which could be harmful to some ICs.

A power supply has inductance and resists sudden changes in current. This is why they are connected between the power supply and ground to act as a very small, local power supply for ICs, because they require quick amount of current when they tend to do sudden switching. They need to be connected as close as possible to your chip.

> Specifically, what purpose do the C1, C2 and C3 capacitors serve?

Some capacitor values/types might surpass others at shunting certain frequencies of noise. So sometimes you might find it useful to use several different-valued, or even different type of capacitors to bypass the power supply.